# Is term "Cruise" correct when you sail on sailboat?

Tags: word-usage

3 questions.

1. Is term "Cruise" correct when you sail on sailboat? I do not mean  day trip but trips from 2 to 30 days. Sailboat is not necessarily big, about 30-50 feet.
2. What do you call  stays in ports and marinas? Is there a different term for stay in inhabitant place?
3. Is terminology for motorboats the same?

I need it for web site I developing, want things to be called right.

Thanks!

Comment: A [cruse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cruise) can be on any sort of boat or ship.

Comment: I doubt many people would think of a 50' sailboat as a [***cruise ship** or **cruise liner***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruise_ship). So I'm not sure you could expect to go on a "cruise" on such a small craft.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have exactly the same doubts too. That is why I am asking!

Comment: @Nick: Well, there's not going to be a "rule" saying whether you can or can't use the word *cruise* in contexts where it *doesn't* mean what most people normally understand by the term. I don't say every craft capable of taking you on a cruise should be big enough to have a ballroom and a resident orchestra, but if you choose to use the word, you must expect at least *some* people to think you're overegging your pudding (a bit like calling an After Eight mint a "sumptuous dessert", on a par with "Death by Chocolate" :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Looks like "cruise" might indeed lead to some misunderstanding. Is there another more suitable term?

Comment: You might want to Google **norfolk broads boat** and see what words others tend to use. Although the continuous verb form ***cruising*** sometimes occurs in that context, I doubt many companies will be offering ***a cruise*** on the Broads. They're generally just ***boating holidays*** (involving ***boat trips*** if the *destinations* are significant).

Comment: @Nick How about "boat ride"? https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&biw=335&bih=221&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22a+boat+ride%22+%22sailboat%22&oq=%22a+boat+ride%22+%22salboat%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...51722.58852.0.59164.11.11.0.0.0.0.901.2726.2-3j2j1j0j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..4.3.838.0CN503Q-rI4; https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&biw=609&bih=400&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22day+boat+ride%22&oq=%22day+boat+ride%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...14874.16802.0.17481.11.8.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..11.0.0.xZglqVFDP-Q

Comment: @Elian "Boat ride" sounds strange to me :) Especially in context of longer cruises like 10  - 30 days.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Check out [Cruising World Magazine](http://www.cruisingworld.com/sailboats/sailboat-reviews). It reports on sailboats ranging from 16 ft. to 50+. *Cruising* is routinely used to describe sailing other than racing.

Comment: You could call it a voyage, maybe?

Comment: @bib Great point, bib! But I doubt "Cruising" can be used as noun...

Comment: In sailing circles (at least in the US), it is constantly used as a noun (although it is a gerund) - *Cruising is a delightful way to spend a Saturday afternoon.*  A *cruise* is the discrete event, with a beginning and an end, *cruising* is the ongoing activity.

Comment: @bib Unfortunately I need term for an event. I am developing website with cruise advertisements. So any sail yacht owner can promote his distinct *Cruise*  with *Stays* in marinas.

Comment: Oops. A commercial cruise business is a different kettle of fish (one that sells tickets). You should do everyone a favor and run your wording past an Admiralty lawyer before you publish. You can't use words like guest, for instance. Cruise, and stays in port are fine, though. Port visits with shore excursions might be more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can cruise in a canoe, no problem. Although its often called voyaging in paddlecraft. Take a look at cruisers forum if you have any doubts.http://www.cruisersforum.com/forums/

Small cruising sailboats under about 23 feet are called pocket cruisers.

2. If you are living on the boat, you are still cruising. Cruising is the most generic term since you are in country under a cruiser's permit issued by the host nation's Customs and Immigration dept. A stay in port is also fine.
3. Yes. The permits are basically the same, and everything else follows.

Bahamas cruising permit process below

http://www.bahamas.com/boating-enter-exit

Comment: thanks. But I did not ask about legal stuff(permits etc). Second questions is just about whether term "Stay"  is right for stays in marinas and ports.

Comment: I didn't realize you were asking about _stay_ as a term. Yes, _stay_ is fine. It's as good as anything else. I made an edit to 2.